What is the default audio setting with Lubuntu 24.04 and how do I modify it?
With Lubuntu Jammy Jellyfish I could change the audio to 24 bit , 48khz by modifying a file in etc/pulse. What is the default audio setting with Lubuntu 24.04 and how do I modify it?

Also asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/what-are-the-audio-settings-for-24-04/4849     Lubuntu started using pipewire in 23.04; https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-23-04-now-uses-pipewire-info-you-should-know-call-for-testing/3907

Ubuntu uses PipeWire as replacement of PulseAudio for its default sound server since Ubuntu 23.04. And, it now uses WirePlumber to manage pipewire session and policy.
WirePlumber has a command line tool called wpctl. It’s useful for getting your device status, properties, and change some settings on the fly, such as set default audio device and change volume.
wpctl status output all audio devices, audio sinks, and audio sources, and use wpctl set-default ID to set default audio I/O device.
Refer to this article Configure Audio Input/Output via WirePlumber in Ubuntu 24.04
